# In Java FileWriter and FileReader, Is it possible to use object?

Tags: java

Please consider these codes: Is it possible to use FileWriter and FileReader with object of class student?

```
Student s1 = new Student();
s1.input();//I want to write this method in a File
FileWriter out2 = new FileWriter("input.txt");
out2.write();
out2.flush();
out2.close();

s1.display();//I want to Read this method in a File
FileReader in2 = new FileReader("input.txt");
in2.read(); 
in2.close();
```

Comment: what do you mean with `I want to display this method in a File`?

Comment: Do you mean there is a method `display` in `Student`, and you want to write its' output to the `File`?

Comment: Then you'll need to pass the `FileWriter` instance to the `display` method, and write to the `FileWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save any **Object** you like with FileOutputStream and get it with FileInputStream (as Object, you need casting after this). Just try it out.
As an example:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream writer = null;
    Student data = new Student();
    try{            
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        writer.writeObject(data);
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Just remember closing it and doing the exception exercise :-).

Since I found an old full-working example-class you may want have a look into it (that's pretty ugly code, but it does the job):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    static boolean checkFile(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            if(file.isFile()){
                return true;
            }
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error creating " + file.toString());
            }
            if (file.isFile() && file.canWrite() && file.canRead())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean writeFile(String dat, Object data){
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream writer = null;

        try{            
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dat);
            writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            writer.writeObject(data);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        finally{
            try{
               if(writer!=null){
                   writer.close();
               }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                if(fos!=null){
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        return true;
    }

    static Student readFile(String dat){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream reader = null;
        Student student = null;

        try{            
            fis = new FileInputStream(dat);
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            student = (Student) reader.readObject();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
               if(reader!=null){
                   reader.close();
               }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                if(fis!=null){
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        return student;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student student = new Student("Horst");
        String filename = "input.txt";
        boolean worked = false;
        if(checkFile(new File(filename)))
            worked=writeFile(filename, student);
        student = new Student("not Horst");
        if(worked)
            student= (Student) readFile(filename);
        System.out.println("Student : " + student.name);
    }

}

class Student implements Serializable{

    public String name;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did this code still getting an error. can you give me a code of FILEREADER and FILEWRITER?

Comment: I knew that (FileInputStream/FileOutputStream) is different from (FileWriter/FileReader).

Comment: take a look of your codes you only use FileInputStream/FileOutputStream. I am asking of FileWriter/FileReader.